# C++ giving output that's off by one

Tags: c++

heres my code:

```
int oupt=0;
for(int i=0, power=number.length()-1; i<number.length(); i++, power--) {
    oupt+=((int)number[i]-48)*pow(5, power);
}
string output = std::to_string(oupt);
```

in this, number is a string of the number i want to convert from base 5 to base 10, for example "414".when i run the code i get the answer as 108 when i know the answer is 109. for all other bases of 5 it gives output which is decremented by one. when i try to print ((int)number[i]-48)*pow(5, power), i get output which makes sense, 100, 5, 4. which add up to 109. the output i get is 108. this is true for all conversions from base 5 to base 10. please help me.

Comment: Are you aware of [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) which can do that for you?

Comment: [Works for me](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c90dd29339c4e6af).

Comment: `((int)number[i]-48)` -- if you *insist* on doing character arithmetics, at least write `((int)number[i]-'0')`... "magic numbers" in source code should be avoided. (Rule of thumb, if you've got anything that's not `0` or `1`, it should be a named constant, not a "naked" number...)

Comment: If `outp` is correct, it makes no sense for `output` to be one number out. You're probably forgetting to recompile your code, or you're running the wrong executable. Either way, this is not a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, so...

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that `pow(5, 2)`, for example, is not really 25. And the underlying reason for that is the most likely explanation for your off-by-1. You will likely fix your problem by getting rid of `pow()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [You are mistaken](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7e5916a1abce2a4).

Comment: Works fine for me too

Comment: for those saying it is not a minimal reproducible problem, this is copy and pasted from my actual program. btw, @asteroids with wings, outp isnt correct, i meant that when i print  ((int)number[i]-48)*pow(5, power) in the for loop, the answers are 100, 5 and 4 which are correct. the variable oupt is 108 which isnt correct.

Comment: @xxsurajbxx A [mcve] is a complete program that we can run. I had to spend time surrounding it with code to produce the one I linked you to above. That was time that _you_ should have spent first, instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any toolset that doesn't give you an exact `double` value for `pow` with integral arguments ought to be considered defective.

But alas the C++ standard permits `pow` to give you an approximation beyond that endemic in double precision floating point arithmetic. Under some standards - such as IEEE754 - some functions (e.g. `sqrt`) and the arithmetic operators are required to return the best floating point number possible, but that rule does not apply to `pow`. It allows compiler and C++ standard library vendors to be lazy and implement `pow(x, y)` as `exp(y * log(x))` for example. And that can undershoot the correct value, and the truncation to an integral type makes the problem pernicious.

This is what's happening to you here.

Putting `std::round` around the `pow` result will probably work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to roll your own text-to-integer conversion, it can be done much more simply:

```
const int base = 5;
int oupt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); ++i) {
    oupt *= base;
    oupt += number[i] - '0'; // works for all character encodings
}

std::string output = std::to_string(oupt);
```

Note: no floating-point math used or needed.

But it's even easier to use the standard library:

```
int oupt = std::stoi(number, nullptr, base);
```

Comment: ...with all the usual cautions over `number` being negative, containing thousands separators, locale, all that nonsense. Do you mind if I sneak in one edit?

Comment: @Bathsheba -- what is a thousands separator in base 5? <g>